# Reactjs/Nodejs/Mongodb : Blob url not working while in img src

Tags: reactjs, image, blob, src

[I am getting this error when I am trying to show the image on frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIWRt.png)

in my mern stack project I am allowing users to upload multiple images and using blob to create the URL of the uploaded images. Using MongoDB to store these URL's. now when I am in my frontend trying to fetch the data and using the same blob URL in the img src tag it's not working. Can you tell me what's the problem here?
Or suggest me what is the best way in which I should do this. is using MongoDB is the best practice in this?

```
          <Swiper
            onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}
            spaceBetween={10}
            slidesPerView={6}
            freeMode={true}
            watchSlidesProgress={true}
            modules={[FreeMode, Navigation, Thumbs]}
            className="mySwiper"
          >
            {productDetails.images?.map((imgurl, index) => (
              <SwiperSlide key={index}>
                <img src={imgurl} alt="product-img" />
              </SwiperSlide>
            ))}
          </Swiper>
        </div>

<div className="media-add-files-box">
                            <input
                              type="file"
                              name="images"
                              ref={imageUploadInput}
                              className="image-upload-input"
                              multiple
                              accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/webp, image/jpg"
                              onChange={handleSelectFile}
                              onChangeCapture={handleAdFormValues("images")}
                            ></input>
                            <button
                              type="button"
                              className="media-add-btn"
                              onClick={triggerImageUploader}
                            >
                              Add photos
                            </button> 

function handleSelectFile(e) {
    const selectedFiles = e.target.files;
    if (!selectedFiles || !selectedFiles[0]) return null;
    setIsImageSelected(true);
    const selectedFilesArray = Array.from(selectedFiles);
    const imagesArray = selectedFilesArray.map((file) => {
      return URL.createObjectURL(file);
    });
    setSelectedImages((previousImages) => previousImages.concat(imagesArray));
    setAdFormValues({
      ...adFormValues,
      images: [...imagesArray],
    });
    console.log(adFormValues.images);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[MDN: URL: createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static)

> The URL lifetime is tied to the document in the window on which it was
> created. The new object URL represents the specified File object or
> Blob object.

You are utilizing this function in your code to generate URLs that will not be relevant once that particular browser session closes.

There are various solutions for dealing with images: storing the binary data directly in your DB, storing the image on your server and then the URL to the file in the DB, or using a cloud service e.g. Cloudinary to host the files and provide you a URL to reference in your code. Which solution to use depends entirely on the scope and needs of your project.

It's not clear from your code where or how images are being uploaded to a server (yours or external service), but if you're just trying to use the aforementioned blob function on its own then this won't work because you're not actually storing images anywhere except in memory within that particular browser session.